# Can you please help me to fiqure out this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Can we figure out the pattern of these sequence?!

$k=3$ :

{$15,15,3$}

$k=4$ :

{$28,28,6$}

$k=5$ :

{$45,45,10$}

$k=6$ :

{$66,66,15$}

I think there is a relationship between these sequences and the triangular numbers.

Comment: This is different from the one in your last post, especially the values for $k=3$ and $4$ are the same. For the one in your last post, we see that the first two are $k(2k-1)$ and the last entries are triangular numbers.

Comment: @player3236 Thanks! I have edited it.

Comment: "*Can we figure out the pattern*"  No.  Not without a lot of additional detail in terms of where these came from in the first place, e.g. if they are an answer to a counting problem or appears in nature as a result of some welldefined process, etc...  There are uncountably infinitely many different sequences which start this way

Comment: @JMoravitz I have already answered the question.

Comment: You are fooling yourself if you think you have answered it in the only possible way.  There is no way to say one answer is more or less correct than any other answer.

Comment: Even among the well known named sequences, there are multiple who have $15,28,45,66,\dots$.  Who is to say that the next number should have been [$91$](http://oeis.org/A000384) rather than [$95$](http://oeis.org/A212087) or [$99$](http://oeis.org/A240944) or any of the others...  You say you "*think there is a relationship between these sequences and the triangular numbers*" however without firm unambiguous description of where the sequences came from, how they started, how they continue, or how they can be calculated unambiguously, that could only have been a *guess* and not necessarily true.

Comment: I emphasize again, you were asking about finding **the** sequence... the usage of the article **the** as opposed to an article like **a** or **an** implying that you are looking for a single answer thinking that only one possible answer exists and that is wrong.  If you had phrased this as looking for **a** *common named* sequence which starts this way, that would be a different story.  We could have told you to look at hexagonal numbers and triangular numbers.  That question would have been fine.  You did not ask that question however, you asked an impossible question.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks! Thanks!

Comment: @JMoravitz I am now prohibited from asking questions, why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fortunately, I have made it out and represent the sequence as a product of two different binomials. The expression that represent these sequences is

$\binom{k}{i-1} \binom{2k-i+1}{3-i}$.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s one possibility:
$$
\left(k(2k-1),k(2k-1),\binom k2\right).$$
Note also that
$$
k(2k-1)=\binom{2k}2.
$$

Comment: Interesting, how come when it is a well known fact that general form can not be determined from finite terms people still give answers?

Comment: @jimjim That’s why I said a possibility.

Comment: My answer is absolutely true, why voted down.